# How to use whisker parameter of boxplot on violin plot for seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

The seaborn box plot has `whis='range'` to plot on min/max outliers, but violin plot does not have this in its documentation. How can I use the boxplot parameter in the violin one?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

a=[195.0, 245.0, 142.0, 237.0, 153.0, 238.0, 168.0, 145.0, 229.0, 138.0, 176.0, 116.0, 252.0, 148.0, 199.0, 162.0, 134.0, 163.0, 130.0, 339.0, 152.0, 208.0, 152.0, 192.0, 163.0, 249.0, 113.0, 176.0, 123.0, 189.0, 150.0, 207.0, 184.0, 153.0, 228.0, 153.0, 170.0, 118.0, 302.0, 197.0, 211.0, 159.0, 228.0, 147.0, 166.0, 156.0, 167.0, 147.0, 126.0, 155.0, 138.0, 159.0, 139.0, 111.0, 133.0, 134.0, 131.0, 156.0, 240.0, 207.0, 150.0, 207.0, 265.0, 151.0, 173.0, 157.0, 261.0, 186.0, 195.0, 158.0, 272.0, 134.0, 221.0, 131.0, 252.0, 148.0, 178.0, 206.0, 146.0, 217.0, 159.0, 190.0, 156.0, 172.0, 159.0, 141.0, 167.0, 168.0, 218.0, 191.0, 207.0, 164.0]

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

# Seaborn violin plot
#sns.violinplot(data=a, whis='range') doesn't work
sns.violinplot(data=a)

# Normal boxplot has full range, same in Seaborn boxplot
# axes.boxplot(a, whis='range')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What exactly would you like the `whis='range'` argument to result in for the violinplot?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I would like the boxplot's (inside the violin plot) min/max whiskers to reach the top and bottom of the violin plot, which can be achieved with `whis='range'` on a normal boxplot.

Comment: late edit, but I meant to say it to touch the top and bottom of the violin plot when `sns.violinplot(data=a, cut=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution can of course be to overlay a normal boxplot, which does have the `whis='range'` argument available, over the seaborn violin plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

a=[195.0, 245.0, 142.0, 237.0, 153.0, 238.0, 168.0, 145.0, 229.0, 138.0, 176.0, 116.0, 252.0, 148.0, 
   199.0, 162.0, 134.0, 163.0, 130.0, 339.0, 152.0, 208.0, 152.0, 192.0, 163.0, 249.0, 113.0, 176.0, 
   123.0, 189.0, 150.0, 207.0, 184.0, 153.0, 228.0, 153.0, 170.0, 118.0, 302.0, 197.0, 211.0, 159.0, 
   228.0, 147.0, 166.0, 156.0, 167.0, 147.0, 126.0, 155.0, 138.0, 159.0, 139.0, 111.0, 133.0, 134.0, 
   131.0, 156.0, 240.0, 207.0, 150.0, 207.0, 265.0, 151.0, 173.0, 157.0, 261.0, 186.0, 195.0, 158.0, 
   272.0, 134.0, 221.0, 131.0, 252.0, 148.0, 178.0, 206.0, 146.0, 217.0, 159.0, 190.0, 156.0, 172.0, 
   159.0, 141.0, 167.0, 168.0, 218.0, 191.0, 207.0, 164.0]

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

# Seaborn violin plot
sns.violinplot(data=a, color="#af52f4", inner=None, linewidth=0, saturation=0.5)

# Normal boxplot has full range, same in Seaborn boxplot
axes.boxplot(a, whis='range', positions=np.array([0]),
            showcaps=False,widths=0.06, patch_artist=True,
            boxprops=dict(color="indigo", facecolor="indigo"),
            whiskerprops=dict(color="indigo", linewidth=2),
            medianprops=dict(color="w", linewidth=2 ))

axes.set_xlim(-1,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wish there was a more intuitive method, but this works just as good.